# Beyond Compare 3 Ignore Case

Tags: beyondcompare3

This should be easy but I can't find any adviceon SO or Scooter forums on how to make the folder compare be case insensitive.  I'm on version 3.3.4 and I'm comparing a folder of Visual Basic files.

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE: I finally found it - there's a button to ignore unimportant differences in the folder compare view.

Answer (score 2):

The folder compare view has a button to ignore unimportant differences - that is different from version 2.x.